# How can we know what superpixel each pixel belongs to in MatLab?

Tags: matlab

I'm doing a program in matlab and I want to know which superpixel each pixel belongs to.

I run the following example:

```
I = imread('barco3.jpg');
figure
imshow(I)
[l,c] = size(I);
[L,N] = superpixels(I,500);
[m,n] = size(L);
```

As far I understood, the label matrix L should have the same size of the image and with the label matrix we are able to know what pixels belongs to each superpixel. But when I check the size of the image and the size of label matrix, they are different in the colunm size.

```
l = 331  
c = 1500
m = 331
n = 500
```

So I think I'm not able to discover what superpixel each pixel belongs to in this way. So how I can proceed to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some timing trying to understand I finally realized my error. The image was RGB one and when get sizing of a RGB image, the colunms count the three chanels, that's why the values are different.